# What exactly is a mole?

Tags: units

I have some trouble understanding exactly what a mole represents. As I understand, one unit mole is 1/12 of the mass of an atom of carbon-12 (thus it is the mass of one nucleon?). What is a mole, then?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

A mole is nothing more than a countable number of things.  Specifically, it is approximated by 6.02 × 10<sup>23</sup> number of things.  Hence, you can have a mole of argon atoms, a mole of electrons, or a mole of house keys all of which contain approximately 6.02 × 10<sup>23</sup> of their respective items.  Note that each of these groups of things will have a *different* mass.

What you are referring to as 1/12 of a <sup>12</sup>C atoms is not a mole, but an atomic mass unit.

Comment: +1 ... it's just like you would use the word "dozen" for the number 12.

Comment: as Luksen says, it is a short hand, as its easier to say in brief than in full...

Comment: The comparison to "dozen" is very apt - it is indeed the same thing, just with a much larger number. (Note that, as Jason alluded to in his answer, we don't know _exactly_ what that number is, but it's something that we could, in principle, figure out if our technology ever gets advanced enough.)

Comment: So I never understand how "mole", whose dimension is actually 1, be a fundamental unit in SI.

Comment: @Karsus: consider it a "fake unit," i.e. a unit whose value is really just a number. Even if it doesn't represent anything other than a number, you can still do with it all the normal things you can do with units. (Same applies for the radian, by the way, which is equal to 1.)

Comment: @Karsus, 1st, a "dimension of 1" does not exist. (You meant dimensionless, I assume) The dimension of the mole is the mole, Just like the kilogram is a kilogram by definition.

Comment: @Karsus: it's not fundamental.  It's defined so that there's a nice relationship between the atomic mass unit and the gram, so that chemists have to think less about units.

Comment: Obligatory XKCD http://what-if.xkcd.com/4/

Answer (score 10):

A mole is like saying "a dozen," as Luksen points out in a comment.  But why pick $(6.02)(10^{23})$ instead of, say, $(6.07)(10^{24})$?  The reason is that the number was strategically picked such that the weight, in grams, of a mole would be numerically exactly the same as its molecular weight.  It is a number that was formulated for the convenience of the chemist (just like the "dozen" was created for the convenience of... uh... someone... the baker?  No, that was 13...)

So, for instance, if you know you have a mole of a substance, you can weigh that mole, in grams, to find the molecular weight without doing any math (like 18.0 grams is about a mole of water, which has a molecular weight of about 18.0).  If, on the other hand, you want a mole of a substance and you know its molecular weight (as you almost always do) you can weigh it out in grams to get exactly a mole.

Answer (score 4):

The mole is of such great use because of the predictable and unique relationship between the number of atoms (counted in moles) in a sample and the sample's easily measured weight or mass (depending on your unit system).

> The mass per mole of a substance is called its molar mass. Since the
>   standard unit for expressing the mass of molecules or atoms (the
>   dalton or atomic mass unit) is defined as 1/12 of the mass of a 12C
>   atom, it follows that the molar mass of a substance, measured in grams
>   per mole, is exactly equal to its mean molecular or atomic mass,
>   measured in daltons; which is to say, to the substance's mean
>   molecular or atomic weight.
>   -Wikipedia

For example: one mole (6.02X10^23 atoms) of Carbon atoms has a mass of 12.011 grams, which is also the atomic weight of Carbon in Daltons ([shown in this periodic table](http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-Q_mcKbGutWw/TfEuTdojy-I/AAAAAAAAGH4/LulenJnl7zQ/s1600/table.gif)). The molar mass of water (2 hydrogen atoms and 1 oxygen atom) =  2*(1.0079) + 1*(15.999) = 18.0148 grams (I am using a lot decimal places for effect despite that being impractical in real life).

Answer (score 2):

I mole is just a way to represent a number of atoms. Instead of saying 12 eggs we can also say a dozen. Similarly one mole of carbon is the same as saying $6.02\cdot10^{23}$ atoms of carbon.